# как найти координаты view в окне AlertDialog относительно экрана?

Tags: android, layout, android-alertdialog

У меня есть view , находящийся в layout , который установлен в AlertDialog , мне нужно найти координаты view относительно ВСЕГО экрана , то есть: сделать поправку на расстояние от левого-верхнего угла view до левого-верхнего угла окна AlertDialog и далее до левого-верхнего угла экрана.

Answer (score 1):

Можете попробовать использовать подобную функцию которая возвращает `Point` обьект с значениями `x, y.`

```
public static Point getLocationView(View view){
    int[] location = new int[2];
    view.getLocationOnScreen(location);
    return new Point(location[0], location[1]);
}
```

Пример использования:

```
Point viewALocation = getLocationView(viewA);
```

***UPD:***Вам может помочь метод `onWindowFocusChanged()` который срабатывает при смене фокуса. 
Пример:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged (boolean hasFocus) {
    Point viewALocation = getLocationView(viewA);
}
```

Comment: Метод `getLocationOnScreen()` (как и `getLocationInWindow()`) возвращает массив с нулями

Comment: @hardhare, дополнил ответ.

Comment: `onWindowFocusChanged()` не помог , но я установил на alertDialog `onShowListener()` и в `onShow()` удалось получить координаты и относительно окна , и относительно экрана - координаты по экрану правильные , а вот по окну какие-то странные: мой view находится в самом верху alertDialog и растянут по всей ширине - то есть координаты в окне должны быть 0 : 0 , но они всегда 32 : 32 , как-будто вокруг видимого alertDialog существует ещё какая-то невидимая рамка

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
{ 
  ...
    int[] coords = {getRelativeLeft(myView), getRelativeTop(myView)};
  ...
}

private int getRelativeLeft(View myView) {
       if (myView.getParent() == myView.getRootView())
           return myView.getLeft();
       else
           return myView.getLeft() + getRelativeLeft((View) myView.getParent());
   }

private int getRelativeTop(View myView) {
       if (myView.getParent() == myView.getRootView())
           return myView.getTop();
       else
           return myView.getTop() + getRelativeTop((View) myView.getParent());
}
```

Comment: `getTop()` / `getLeft()` для view , `view.getParent()` и `view.getRootView()`, тоже возвращают нули